# The meaning of "to have the life"?

Tags: meaning

Mr. Joseph Cambell says:

> We must be willing to get rid of the life we’ve planned, so as to have
>   the life that is waiting for us.

And my question. What does “have the life” mean in this context? Same as “live a life”?

I’m a non-native speaker of English and would be most grateful, if you could give me an answer as a native speaker of English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr Campbell appears to be promoting an approach to life, possibly a philosophy of life or even a religious message.

He says that people must be prepared to abandon their plans and ambitions in order to embrace the approach to life that (he says) is waiting for them.

His Campbell's message is resonant of the promises made by some preachers and lifestyle advocates - as well as the leaders of cults.

His suggestion is that he can lead people to a fuller, more rewarding and meaningful way of living if they are prepared to change their ideas and follow his teachings.

This is his promise of the life that they can have.